# How do you launch the iOS Photos app from another app? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a video recording app and I was wondering if it is possible to create a `button` that says "View Camera Roll" and when you click on that button it would launch the Photos app on your phone.

I see a common use for something like this is `UIImagePickerController` in my actual app which is close to what I want, but I don't want the user to be picking one for something other than just viewing it and browsing through their photos. It would be much easier to just have a link to the actual Photos app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot open the default Photo app. In iOS, an application needs to register for a URL schemes to be opened from elsewhere, and default photo app does not have one.

To learn more about URL Schema, [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html) is the Apple's document

Answer (score 5):

You can use `photos-redirect://` to open the Photos app but since it is not documented Apple can reject your app and you can have problems with it in the future if it stops working.

Comment: why they can reject it? what is wrong with opening some app from a different app?

Comment: Since it is not documented they can simply say "it's private" and block. I'm not saying they WILL, just that they can.